# Weird Characters in PHP File

Tags: php

I have a weird issue where my PHP files have lost their line breaks and appear to have weird box/rectangle shaped characters in them. I have no clue how to fix them and they are interfering with my website.

Comment: Why would people vote down my question??? A little confused on how stackoverflow works...

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suspect it's the nature of the question "How can I fix this thing that I can't be bothered to describe or show you". I mean, atleast provide a screenshot. You'll find quickly that SO appreciates when a question includes brevity, accuracy, and respect. "*weird box/rectangle shaped characters*" doesn't give anyone a lot to go on as evidence of the abundance of answers with questions in them or pure guesses. Also "*they are interfering with my website from running*" includes no specific details as to HOW its breaking your website. Comes off as very lazy and unappreciative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What editor are you using? That is a symptom of trying to edit Unix format files in MS notepad (amongst other combinations).

Your files have most likely been converted by an FTP transaction of uploading them to the remote server (because the client correctly used `TYPE A`) and not converted back when you retrieved them (because it incorrectly used `TYPE I`).

Either get a better editor (like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [EditPadPro](http://www.editpadpro.com/)) or force your FTP client into ASCII mode (`TYPE A`).

FYI, on *nix a line ending character is LF only (`\n`), on Windoze it is CRLF (`\r\n`) and on Mac it is CR only (`\r`).

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will try NotePad++ - I was using notepad - thats probably why

Answer (score 2):

By the way, this can still occasionally happen in Notepad++ if you use Notepad++'s FTP plugin and do not set the FTP plugin (nppftp) settings to ASCII. That is why I found this post.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing the difference between Windows and Unix line breaks.

Windows uses `CR+LF` whereas Unix-based systems simply use `LF`.

See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_break_(computing)#Representations

PHP will parse both, so I doubt that is the reason your code isn't running.  Of course, with no file posted, this is only a best guess (and a common issue).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Brad said, you probably have the wrong line breaks.  Assuming that you're on a *nix system, run `dos2unix <filename>`, and that will replace the Windows endline `\r\n` with the *nix endline character of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You just enabled "Show Linebreaks" or "Show special characters" in your editors menu options. So now, rather than an invisible "\n" or "\r\n" you are seeing a representation of them.